# How to copy image from Drawable folder to internal storage ( Xamarin Forms )

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, drawable

**I want a method that will allow me to copy an image from the Drawable folder to the internal storage, i searched the internet for solutions but i found some of them that did not work for me like this one :**

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "ic_launcher.PNG");
outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close()
```

Comment: did you add internal storage permission to your manifest

Comment: this is Java code.  It should be fairly trivial to convert it to C# using the Xamarin docs

Comment: It's clear what you want, but what 'does not work for you'? This is not the place to post things like: write me this code, I need it. I also wonder, why you would need to store a embedded resource on external storage?